# implementation of react-input-mask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, input-mask

I'm using React with reatstrap and, I need to use some type of input mask, to prevent the user from typing characters in the field, and to make an indentation for monetary values (example = $ 10.00)

I found this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-masked-input

I tried this code:

```
  <CurrencyInput className = "form-control" value = {this.state.input_value}
              onChange = {
                      e => this.setState (
                          {input_value: e.target.value, input_value_per_numb_days: e.target.value / this.state.numb_days}
                      )
                  }
              />
```

however, it doesn't work, it just changes my field type to number.
How can I use this mask to handle the entered values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to ["Docs"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-masked-input)

> **Usage notes:**
> Calls onChange prop after updating its internal value. First argument is the original event, the second is the masked value.

The `onChange` event got a second argument with the masked value:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const [numbDays, setNumbDays] = useState(0);

  const numberOfDays = 7;

  const maskInput = (e, masked) => {
    setInput(masked);
    setNumbDays(masked / numberOfDays);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CurrencyInput name="myInput" onChange={maskInput} value={input} required />
      <h1>input / {numberOfDays} = {numbDays}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: but if I need 'onChange' to change the state value for example?

Comment: I understand what you said, but it is hard for me to understand the reason for these lines written in the domunetation and in the example on the same page it shows an implementation without using 'onChange'.